# Google Authentication not found error JHBUILD, Configuring Evolution Data Server

Tags: server, gnome, evolution, jhbuild

I have recently installed jhbuild. On running

```
jhbuild build gnome-calendar
```

i was on 46th step of building [46/47] which is related to evolution-data-server while configuring I get this error at the end

```
`checking if Google authentication support is enabled... yes
checking for GOOGLE_AUTH... no

configure: error: 

Libraries to support Google authentication prompts not found,
or versions not new enough.

If you want to disable Google authentication support,
please append --disable-google-auth to configure.`
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `configure.ac` [code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnome/Desktop/evolution/data-server/configure.ac#487), it looks like you need `webkitgtk-3.0` and `json-glib-1.0` (the `libjson-glib-1.0-0-dev` and `libjson-glib-dev` packages)